# Flutter Chrome Debugging: API calls don't work at all

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart, flutter-web

I'm developing a simple web/Android Flutter App. Everything works fine on Android, but when I try debugging it on Chrome (web-javascript), none of my API calls work.

Debugger stops in **ticker.dart** > **TickerFuture** > **_complete()** and this message appears in the console, and the API call continues forever.

`ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression '_primaryCompleter'`

I've tried using CORS and try catch blocks to see if i can get more info about the error.

This is an example API call:

```
Future<bool> login(LoginData l) async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + "/login/");

      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: {"email": l.name, "password": l.password},
          headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body == "true";
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load books');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception('Failed to load books');
    }
  }
```

Comment: There were some issues with debugging when Chrome v100 released. Flutter 2.10.5 was recently released to fix some of these issues, so if you haven't already upgraded to it, it's worth trying to see if that resolves the problem (or at least makes debugging work better to track down the issue): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#2105-april-18-2022

Comment: if the end point works in postman then it will work in flutter.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny It was probably version issue. Updated it and works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Pabloloarag great, glad to hear! I copied my comment into an answer if you want to mark it as being answered/resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues with debugging in Chrome after Chrome v100 released.

Flutter 2.10.5 was released to fix some of these issues:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#2105-april-18-2022

> [flutter/101224](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101224) - Flutter web debugger fails when using chrome 100 or greater.